# which 2-pin Molex connector is this?

Tags: connector, identification, plug, socket

I've been looking at Molex's website for hours and I can't identify this connector.  It's the motor connector on a cheap quadcopter.  Does anyone know what connector it is?  Thanks for your help.

[image: picture of plug]

[image: picture of receptacle]

Comment: Is this some sort of JST connector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that this is [Molex PicoBlade](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoblade&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction).
If that's the case, then the pitch should be 1.25mm.

Please measure the pitch (center-to-center distance between the pins) and update your question with that information.